# How to return row with diffrent value if "where" has not been met in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, join, where-clause

I have problem with receiving rows if id from one table dont match second one. 
If zamowienia.id_telefon is null or dont match i dont recive whole row.
I want to instead get column crm2018.telefon.numer with "0" or null value. Please help :)

I tried something like that but its obvious syntax eror:

```
SELECT 
    crm2018.zamowienia.*,
    crm2018.telefon.numer 
FROM
    crm2018.zamowienia 
    JOIN crm2018.telefon 
WHERE
    if (zamowienia.id_telfon != "0")  zamowienia.id_telefon = telefon.id_telefon else crm2018.telefon.numer as "0"
```

Here's working code but with missing rows.

```
SELECT 
    crm2018.zamowienia.*,
    crm2018.telefon.numer 
FROM 
    crm2018.zamowienia 
    JOIN crm2018.telefon 
WHERE 
    zamowienia.id_telefon = telefon.id_telefon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use LEFT JOIN instead of (INNER) JOIN.

Accordingly, you need to move the join condition from the WHERE clause to the ON clause of the join, to avoid filtering out unmatched records. Please note that as it is, your query has a JOIN without ON clause : this is a syntax error in all SQL dialects.

Finally, I would recommend using table aliases in the query : this makes it easier to read and to maintain.

```
SELECT 
    z.*,
    t.numer 
FROM
    crm2018.zamowienia AS z 
    LEFT JOIN crm2018.telefon AS t
        ON z.id_telefon = t.id_telefon
```

When no record is available in crm2018.telefon for the given crm2018.zamowienia, the record will still be displayed, with all columns coming from crm2018.telefon showing NULL values.

If needed, you can turn NULL values to 0 with the COALESCE() function, like :

```
COALESCE(t.numer, 0)
```

Comment: wow it was just missing left join, the more you know XD, amazing dude